# c# reversing and serializing a dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Was wondering is it possible to reverse a dictionary in a single LINQ statement?

The structure is as follows;

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> original = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() 
    {
        {"s", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" }},
        {"m", new List<string>() { "4", "5", "6" }},
        {"l", new List<string>() { "7", "8", "9" }},
        {"xl", new List<string>() { "10", "11", "12" }},
    };
```

which i would like to convert to a dictionary of type;

```
Dictionary<string, string> Reverse = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"1", "s"},
        {"2", "s"}, //and so on
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `SelectMany` to split the value sublists, and then reverse the Keys & Values into a new Dictionary using `ToDictionary`

```
var result = original
    .SelectMany(k=> k.Value.Select(v => new { Key = v, Value = k.Key } ))
    .ToDictionary( t=> t.Key, t=> t.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
var reversed = original.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(y, x.Key)));
```

then you get:

> 1 - s
>
> 2 - s
>
> 3 - s
>
> 4 - m
>
> 5 - m

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var result = (from kvp in original
              from value in kvp.Value
              select new {Key = value, Value = kvp.Key}).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Or, if you prefer the method syntax:

```
var result = original.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new {Key = v, Value = kvp.Key}))
                     .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use the `SelectMany` LINQ extension method:

```
var original = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
                   {
                       { "s", new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" } },
                       { "m", new List<string> { "4", "5", "6" } },
                       { "l", new List<string> { "7", "8", "9" } },
                       { "xl", new List<string> { "10", "11", "12" } },
                   };

var keyValuePairs = original.SelectMany(o => o.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v, o.Key)));
```